# Filtering a pandas df with any of the list values

Tags: python, pandas, filter, lambda

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
df
0       PL
1       PL
2       PL
3       IT
4       IT
        ..
4670    DE
4671    NO
4672    MT
4673    FI
4674    XX
Name: country_code, Length: 4675, dtype: object
```

I am filtering this by germany country tag 'DE' via:

```
df = df[df.apply(lambda x: 'DE' in x)]
```

If I would like to filter with more countries than I have to add them manually via: `.apply(lambda x: 'DE' in x or 'GB' in x)`. However I would like to create a countries list and generate this statement automaticly.

Something like this:

```
countries = ['DE', 'GB', 'IT']
df = df[df.apply(lambda x: any_item_in_countries_list in x)]
```

I think I can filter df 3 times and then merge these pieces back via `concat()`, however is there a more generic function to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.isin()`:

```
df[df['country_code'].isin(['DE', 'GB', 'IT'])]
```

---

Performance comparison:

```
import timeit
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'country_code': ['DE', 'GB', 'IT', 'MT', 'FI', 'XX'] * 1000})

%timeit df[df['country_code'].isin(['DE', 'GB', 'IT'])]
409 µs ± 19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df['country_code'].apply(lambda x: x in ['DE', 'AT', 'GB'])
1.35 ms ± 474 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: `.apply(lambda x: x in ['DE', 'AT', 'GB'])`, also work do you want to do a benchmark?

Comment: @oakca, apply is considered a bottleneck operation, I can make a comparisson, but I don't thinky apply can beat many standard methods of pandas.

Comment: I will accept, but for documentation reasons, if you make a easy benchmark and show it in your answer would be good.

Comment: @oakca  added performance check.

Answer (score 1):

If you have column names the you can try this

```
countries = ['DE', 'GB', 'IT']
df[df['country_code'].isin(countries)]
```

Comment: He showed a pd.Series, you can see the name of the series (or column name) at the bottom of his example.

Comment: `.apply(lambda x: x in ['DE', 'AT', 'GB'])`, also work do you want to do a benchmark?

Comment: Oakca, you can do that using colab and py calling %timeit on the filter line